# Bitlocker eDrive + multi-boot possible?

Tags: windows-10, ssd, multi-boot, bitlocker

Is it possible to activate the bitlocker eDrive encryption on a multi-boot system?

I encrypted both my system and data partition using bitlocker on my Win8.1 system, that I want to upgrade to Win10. I also want to be able to boot up a small linux partition, which I haven't configured yet. My SSD is eDrive ready (Samsung Evo 840). 
Has anyone ever tried this/ is this even possible?

Comment: This should be possible provide you make it a multi-boot before you encrypt it.  Both OSs would need to support Bitlocker though.  This means Professional version of 8.1 and 10

Comment: "system partition" in Microsoft terms shouldn't be encrypted (system partition - where boot files are, both MBR and GPT disks). "boot partition" is where Windows is installed.